# Position The Cursor Blinking Line in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox

I have a textbox, and inside that textbox i have a text. The text displays hello.

When i run the program the cursor starts from the letter o in hello

(| =cursor)

ex. Hello|

how do i make the cursor start before the letter H

ex.|Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it with the following code

```
  TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
  TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
```